# Nested TransactionScope

Tags: asp.net, transactions

I need to use nested transaction scopes to perform some actions:

1)Insert Address

2) After that insert ContactInfo

3) After that insert UserInfo

```
//one class
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                {
                    user.ContactInfo = BLContactInfo.Add(user.ContactInfo);
                    BEUser newUser  = DLSecurity.CreateUser(user);
                    transaction.Complete();

    //.......
    }

    //two class

    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                    {
                        contactInfo.Address = BLAddress.Add(contactInfo.Address);
                        BEContactInfo newContactInfo = DLContactInfo.Add(contactInfo);
                        transaction.Complete();

                        return newContactInfo;
                }
```

I don't know: Is this way good? Can I avoid using nested transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah - nothing says why you need nested transactions. The transaction scope should NOT (!) be within the class. Create ONE transaction OUTSIDE on the top level, then make all calls.